# Google cloud appengine 1.9.54 Release

Tags: google-app-engine, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, multiple-instances, app-engine-flexible

We are deploying ASP.NET Core application on Appengine **Flex** and in Instances Summary on Dashboard page appears strange **1.9.54** appengine release as well as **Flex** release. What that might be?

[image: From google cloud console]

Our app.yaml:

```
env: flex
runtime: aspnetcore
resources:
cpu: 8
memory_gb: 14.4

automatic_scaling:
 min_num_instances: 8
 max_num_instances: 20
 cool_down_period_sec: 180
 cpu_utilization:
  target_utilization: 0.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app's dashboard summary indicates your app has both:

- standard env GAE instances (`1.9.54` being the version of the GAE sandbox/infra running those instances), possibly from older service version(s) not yet deleted
- flexible env GAE instances

You can play with the `Service` and/or `Version` selection boxes above the summary to identify which service/version those instances correspond to.